# DBus memory build up

Tags: d-bus

I'm using dbus commands to control Spotify, but over time I'm noticing memory buildup. I was using htop to check out what is happening, and I noticed a process called xfce4-notifyd taking up a LOT of memory. I executed `killall kfce4-notifyd` and my swap memory literally dropped 400 megabytes.

I can only assume dbus is somehow getting clogged up, but everything I'm using dbus for is single quick commands. I ran `dbus-monitor --session` and it seems it's storing ALL commands running into it... Is there a way to "flush" dbus's cache, if it even has one? Ideally without disrupting new dbus commands going in.